# Searching for inbuilt listener in trace for syslog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, syslog, trace

I want to configure trace listener to log into syslog. I searched alot for finding existing listener but no success till now. Is there any inbuilt listener in trace like in log4net  through which I can write into syslog directly without making code changes.

```
 <configuration>
      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
          <listeners>
            <add name="myListener" 
                 type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                 initializeData="fileSizeThreshold=512, fileSizeUnit=kilobytes, 
                 fileAgeThreshold=1, fileAgeUnit=months, fileNameTemplate='{0}\MyApp-{1:MMM-yy}.log'"/>
            <remove name="Default" />
          </listeners>
        </trace>
      </system.diagnostics>
    </configuration>
```